# Server continues to function in Client/Server C application even after closing sockets

Tags: c, unix, tcp, client-server

I am making a Tic Tac Toe application, with client/server. When pressing CTRL+C I have a custom handler that closes the sockets (the listening one as well), and then exits. However, if I try to run the program again, sometimes it gives an error that the port is used so it cannot bind, which lasts from several minutes (or until restart), to some seconds and sometimes it doesn't happen at all. I suspect this is a normal process, however I would like a second opinion. Also, any suggestions on how to avoid this would be appreciated!

EDIT: forgot to mention that, again SOMETIMES, killing the terminal works.

Comment: Could you provide a working example?

Comment: the code is around 500 lines so I guess you don't mean that. One instance of it happening is, when a player wins for example, both the server and the two clients are killed (sockets closed, processes killed). Sometimes after that I need to wait or restart.

Comment: How do you handle your clients, `threads`, `select()` ...?

Comment: Are you using `signal()`? ->  [What happens if you use it?](https://pastebin.com/raw/2nYxb83m)

Answer (score 2):

There is a connection (identified by IP address and port number) still in `TIME_WAIT` state. This state exists because there might be some IP packages around in the net that were sent to this connection. You probably get an error `EADDRINUSE` when you try to bind the socket.
You can check this with `netstat`.

Read about socket option `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT`.

related:
[Socket options SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT, how do they differ? Do they mean the same across all major operating systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t)